# IOS - Localizable String after upgrade

Tags: ios, ios7, upgrade, localizable.strings

I released few month ago an App compatible with iOS starting from version 6.1 .
this app have  default Localization (the Localizable.string was in the root App/Content, not in the en.jproj)

now I would to upgrade this app (It'll run starting from ios7) and I localized it.
Before to submit the app to the Store I made this test to see that all will work fine:

I download from Store the last version available. 
I executed it, inserted few datas. 
Then I executed the new app from xcode the new app.

well, the localized string are NOT elaborated.
they are located within the package in the correct location (en.lproj,it.lproj).

- is the correct way to verify that the upgrade will success?
- could it
  be that it remains the old Localizable.string somewhere in the app
  and this last one have priority?
- how can handle this without issue,
  or worst, to force user to delete ad download again the app?

thanks